# hive -hiveconf -f xxx.sql error

Tags: sql, hive

my sql file content is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE  unLock(logTime TIMESTAMP, ystID STRING,deviceID STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="$$")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION concat(hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logHive/unLock/,${hiveconf:logdir});
```

and my shell script file content is :

```
hive -hiveconf logdir="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d/')" -f /home/yst/create.sql
```

when I run the shell file in cmd,the error is:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:9 mismatched input 'concat' expecting StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification
```

I don't known why. I just want to the hive table's location is the current day files.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested yet, but this might work:

`LOCATION 'hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logHive/unLock/${hiveconf:logdir}'`

Comment: also failed. FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /logHive/useAppDuration/$(hiveconf:logdir) from hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logHive/useAppDuration/$(hiveconf:logdir) is not a valid DFS filename.)

Comment: use this, can't get the logdir value